# Apache on Raspberry Pi deny/allow IP of directory

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi

I know that this has been asked before but I just can't get it to work. What I want to achieve is to make it so that the index.php file and others in the /var/www directory can only be accessed when connected to my home network, but phpmyadmin is available through a server hosted on Weaved (weaved.com). Ideally it would make everything "private"(only accessible when on the home network) except phpmyadmin and the MySQL databases. When using the code bellow I can still acces the page from any IP address I like, why? Thanks in advance!

```
  <Directory /var/www/>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from 192.168.0.240
  </Directory>
```

Comment: Are you restarting the Apache server after making that change?

Comment: @drew010 Yes I am, using "sudo service apache2 restart".

Comment: It should work - are you adding it to the correct VirtualHost?

Comment: @drew010 I'm adding it to the apache2.conf file. I'm pretty sure it's the correct file since when I copy pasted some very similar code with a password prompt above it, it worked.

Comment: Depending on what OS flavor you are using on the Pi, it might need to go in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` (the typical default vhost on debian/ubuntu Apache installs if apache2.conf isn't working.

Comment: @drew010 it had a "AllowOverride None" for the /var/www directory set which I changed to "AllowOverride All" now, certainly a step in the right direction I think, but it can still acces the site from any IP I like....